# MySQL errorcode 1005, errno 105

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've designed DB in MySQL Workbench - throught EER Model.

Error log:
http://pastebin.com/iMJP5aRT

And my SQL code:
http://pastebin.com/QzZvd164

And my model:
www55.zippyshare.com/v/52649774/file.html

**What's wrong with it? It's weird becouse it was created in MySQL Workbench, not on my own.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not referencing to a primary key! (in table patients):

```
REFERENCES `lekarze`.`visits` (`idpatients` )
```

and (in table visits)

```
PRIMARY KEY (`idvisits`) )
```

Don't match.

You are not referencing to a primary key of your visits table.

Best,
Yannis

Comment: Now that I looked again at your code I saw that you may want to have the FOREIGN KEY on the visits table referencing the patients table rather than how you did it.

Comment: Yes you're right. Thanks. If you know, please show me a good article about relationship in MySQL.

Comment: Yes sure, here you are: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Maybe you want to start by drawing your tables on paper and then implent with the command line - my opinion is that you'll learn more if you work with the command line rather than with some 'code generators' ;)

This maybe helps you as well.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-relationship_model

Best,